# Adding a scroll to left panel in bootstrap powered page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote a page for a restaurant as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rjwe9pb6/).
I want scroll to be added to left panel. I'm using `over-flow-y: scroll` for left panel as shown below:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4" id="offers">
                    <div id="offerOne">
                        <img src="images/images.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block">
                    </div>
                    <div id="offerTwo">
                        <img src="images/images.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary center-block">View offer</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="offerThree">
                        <img src="images/images.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary center-block">View offer</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**`css:`**

```
#offers {
        margin-top: 0.5%;
        height: 100;
        overflow-y: auto;
        background: #F6F6F6 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    }
```

But scrolling isn't coming. How can I do it?

Comment: set max-height then only overflow will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try updating value of height from 100 to 100px

```
#offers {
        margin-top: 0.5%;
        height: 100px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        background: #F6F6F6 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your css for `#offers` is not specifying a valid height.  If you would like it to be 100 pixels tall, you need to change it like so:

```
height: 100px;
```

After this change, it should scroll properly, otherwise the div will grow to fit its contents.

Comment: yeah, mine was a typo

Answer (score 0):

Use max-height. over flow will work only with max-height or max-width.

```
#offers {
        margin-top: 0.5%;
        height: 200px;
        max-height: 100px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        background: #F6F6F6 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    }
```